# In case of Biopython. ImportError: No module named seq

Tags: module, biopython

I am python starter. I installed Biopython and tested it.

BUT.. It is not working well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G212f.jpg)

My module is on here and I checked it by following work through.

Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 17 2015, 23:05:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import Bio
> > >       from Bio.seq import seq
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named seq

I am not.. sure... searching the internet please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find out where it installed and add the path to your pythonpath

```
export PYTHONPATH=<path>
#my path was /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

in your ~/.bashrc  (linux) or ~/.profile file (osx).

Comment: I have two python ver2.7.10 & 3.4.3 I think pythonpath is on ver 3.43. but i installed biopython on 2.7.10.  and I did as follow  export PYTHONPATH=<path>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'  there is another problem... so I felt that I need to more study about python.. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Python is case-sensitive.  Biopython has no "`seq`" module; you need to import "`Seq`" instead:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
```